# Cannot Select a table through a query even though it is fully available

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using MSSMS to try and look at a new db for work. My coworker is having no problem querying the db and its tables, and we have tried refreshing object explorer, deleting and recreating the db, refreshing the cache on intelliSense and dragging the table directly into the query but it is saying that the table name is an invalid object name. I can view whats in the table if I right click and select the top 1000 but I cannot query anything. I have also tried selecting it by doing the "dbo." before the table name. Any ideas on why this would be happening and what to try is much appreciated.

[Here is the proof that it is in the db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCxPF.png)

[Here is my simple query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t82sm.png)

Comment: Your query is running against the "Master" database, you need to open a query windows against your database.

Comment: You  my be trying to run this against the "master" database. they putting in the command use [yourdatabasename] first and then do the select

Comment: Use the database selection drop-down list in the upper left of the SSMS UI to select the database you want to run queries against. It defaults to 'master' which is not the database the table is in.